# Showing that a subset of a metric space is open. Strip in $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: real-analysis

For an open interval $(a,b)$ in $\mathbb R$, show that $\left\{(x,y)\in R^2 : x\in (a,b)\wedge y\in\mathbb R\right\}$ is open in $\mathbb R^2$. I would prefer helpful hints and guidance over an explicit answer. I am having serious difficulty understanding how to show that a set is open, I feel as though it should be easy but right now it seems difficult.

Since $(a,b)$ is open I know for $x\in (a,b)$, there exists $(x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon)$ contained in $(a,b)$, and I understand I essentially have to show that for an arbitrary point in our set, there is an epsilon-ball about our point entirely contained in our set. from here, I feel overwhelmed and almost completely lost.

Comment: Pick a point $P=(x,y)$ in your strip? How far to the boundary? That's a qualifying radius for an open disk centered at $P$.

Comment: The set in question is $(a,b)\times\Bbb R$. We know that both $(a,b)$ and $\Bbb R$ are open in $\Bbb R$. Can you show that for two open subsets $A,B\subseteq X$, it follows that $A\times B$ is open in $X^2$ ?

Comment: I keep thinking (b-a)/2 for my radius? I'm just not sure how this proof is supposed to go

Comment: For any $(x,y)$ on the strip, suppose $x-a=k\gt 0$. Then, consider the open ball $B_{\epsilon}(x,y)$ where $0\lt\epsilon\lt k$

Comment: [Proof without words.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyJeZ.png)

Comment: In the spirit of @GNUSupporter's answer, a [similar demonstration](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/eduz8qllgw) (not quite a proof, and not entirely without words, but more interactive).

Answer (score 1):

*Note: this may not be exactly the answer you are looking for, but it is a point of view worth keeping in mind.*

By *definition*, the product topology is the coarsest (that is, the one with the least possible open subsets) that satisfies the property that the projections on each factor $$\operatorname{pr}_1, \operatorname{pr}_2: \Bbb R\times \Bbb R\to \Bbb R$$
are continuous maps.

Now $\operatorname{pr}_1$ being continuous implies that the preimage $\operatorname{pr}_1^{-1}(U)$ is open in $\Bbb R\times \Bbb R$ for any open subset $U\subset \Bbb R$.

Applying this to $U=(a,b)$ gives you exactly what you want.